# Setter and Getter method for map

Tags: c++, stl

```
string var;

void setvar(string ivar)
{
    var=ivar;
}

string getVar() const
{
    return var;
}
```

as same way how can i write setter and getter method for a map like this

std::map  varmap;

Comment: Getters and setters are an abomination onto OO.

Comment: Here's a document explaining the madness of getters and setters so much more eloquently than I ever could: : http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a getter or setter for a field that's a `std::map` just as you would any other field - just have the getter return a `std::map` and have the setter accept a `std::map`.

Of course, if you have a field that's a `std::map` that you're trying to use getters and setters on, that might suggest that there's a better way to structure the program.  Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do?

**EDIT:** The above answer is for a slightly different question than the one you asked.  It seems like what you're interested in is

> Given a class with a `std::map` as a data member, write a function to set a given key/value pair and a function to return the value associated with a given key.

The setter logic for this is not too hard - you just write a function that takes in the key and value and associates the key with the value.  For example:

```
void put(const string& key, const string& value) {
    varmap[key] = value;
}
```

Writing a getter is trickier because there's no guarantee that there's a value associated with a particular key.  When this happens, you have multiple options.

1. **You could return a sentinel value**.  For example, you might return an empty string if the given value isn't stored in the map anywhere.  This makes the code for using the function easier to read, but risks using an invalid value in code.
2. **You could throw an exception.**  This would be good if it represents a serious error for the given value not to exist.  This has the drawback that if you look up a value, you always need to `try`/`catch` the logic to avoid propagation of errors.
3. **You could associate a default value with the key, then hand that back.**  If you're writing a program that represents a music library, for example, you might hand back "(none)" or "(unknown)" if you tried to look up the artist for a song on which you have no data, for example.

No one of these approaches works best, and you'll need to think over which is most appropriate to your particular circumstance.

Comment: map has key  as a string and value is also string i want to set both(key and value) in one method(setter) and want to retrieve that value from getter method .

Answer (score 1):

Entries in a `std::map<Key, Value>` must have a key and a value.  The normal way of getting and setting them is:

```
my_map[a_key] = new_value;   // set

do_something_with(my_map[a_key]);    // get and use...
```

If you want to add new functions, they probably wouldn't look like what you're proposing because:

- your `set` is only given one parameter despite needing a key and value (admittedly, you could adopt some convention like having the first ':' or '=' separate them), and
- the get() function doesn't provide any key.

You could instead have something more like:

```
void set(const Key&, const Value&);
std::string get(const Key&) const;
```

But, even if you have write permissions to do so, you shouldn't add that directly in the map header file - all C++ programs compiled on that computer will share that file and won't expect it to be modified.  Any small mistake could cause trouble, and if you ship your program to another computer you won't be able to compile it there without making a similar modification - if that computer uses a different C++ compiler the necessary details of that modification may be slightly different too.

So, you can either write your own (preferably templated) class that derives from (inherits) or contains (composition) a std::map, providing your functions in your custom class.  An inheritance based solution is easier and more concise to write:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct My_Map : std::map<Key, Value>
{
    My_Map(...); // have to provide any non-default constructors you want...

    void set(const Key& key, const Value& value) { operator[](key) = value; }

    // if you want entries for non-existent keys to be created with a default Value...
    Value& get(const Key& key) { return operator[](key); }

    --- OR ---

    // if you want an exception thrown for non-existent keys...
    Value& get(const Key& key) { return at(key); }
    const Value& get(const Key& key) const { return at(key); }
};
```

This is slightly dangerous if you're planning to pass My_Maps around by pointer and accidentally end up with a "new My_Map" pointer that's later deleted as a std::map pointer, as in:

```
void f(std::map<int, string>* p) { /* use *p */   delete p; }

My_Map<int, string>* p = new My_Map<int, string>;
f(p);
```

Still, in most programs there's no real danger of accidentally disposing of a map like this, so go ahead and do it.

Further, and this is the kind of thinking that'll make me unpopular with the Standard-fearing purists around here - *because `My_Map` hasn't added any data members or other bases*, the `std::map<>` destructor *probably* does all the necessary tear-down even though it's technically Undefined Behaviour.  I'm **NOT** encouraging you to ignore the issue (and would consider it unprofessional in a job requiring robustness), but you can at least rest a little easier.  I'd be curious to hear from *anyone* with any compiler/settings where it demonstrably doesn't operate safely.

If you use composition, you'll have to write your own "forwarding" functions to let you use My_Map like a std::map, accessing iterators, find, erase, insert etc..  It's a pain.

Comment: in getter method i want to return both key and value as a pair.

Comment: Ganesh: `std::pair<Key, Value> get(const Key& key) const { return std::make_pair(key, at(key)); }

Comment: The OP was not asking about adding getters and setters to the (template) class `std::map`, but adding getters and setters to a custom class where the member variable is a `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

Setter and getter for `std::map` is no different except that you need to pass the necessary parameters for the setter. Assume if I have a `struct` and has a member variable whose type is `std::map`, whose `key` is of type `char` and `data` is of type `int`. Method signatures would be of the format -

- `void setEncode( char* key, int* data, const int& size );` Because, std::map requires a key, data and sizes of these arrays being passed. With out knowing `size`, it is unknown as how far to insert the elements in to the container.
- `std::map<char, int> getEncode() const ;` const key word signifies it a non-modifying member function. Because it's functionality is to just return a variable of type `std::map`.

---

Example -

```
struct myMap
{
    std::map<char, int> encode;
    void setEncode( char* key, int* data, const int& size );
    std::map<char, int> getEncode() const ;
};

void myMap::setEncode( char *key, int* data, const int& size )
{
    int i=0;
    while( i < size )
    {
            encode.insert(std::pair<char, int>(key[i], data[i]));
            ++i ;           
    }
}

std::map<char, int> myMap::getEncode() const
{
    return encode;
}
```

[Results IdeOne](http://ideone.com/ifeQ7). This should give you an idea, but should also follow the general rules what @templatetypedef, @tony suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to set a key value pair in an existing map(probably that's what you want) or create a new map itself?

```
void setvar(string key, int value)
{
    myMap[key] = value;
}

int getVar(string key) const
{
    return myMap[key];
}
```

where int and string are interchangeable

For latter you'll probably have to interate over all map values for setting and getter should be just to return that map pointer.

Comment: Be careful with your `getVar` function - `operator[]` on a `std::map` is not `const` and so this code won't compile.  The reason is that `operator[]` will insert a new value if you try looking up a nonexistent key, and so you'll end up changing the map with the lookup.  You should probably address this somewhere in the code.